# Iron Router OnBefore Hook with Params URL Not Calling Function

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am looking to restrict access to a page using iron router, but the before function doesn't seem to be running.

```
# Limit which challenges can seen to members.
isMemberHook = () ->
    challenge = Challenges.findOne _id: @params._id
    if Meteor.userId() in challenge.members
        @next()
    else
        @redirect '/'

Router.onBeforeAction isMemberHook,
    only: ['/challenge/:_id']
```

Comment: Note: I have only routes like 'admin' that work fine with OnBefore Hooks, but in this case, no luck.  I think the URL having params is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that for routes with "/" you need to use ".".

So in this case I used:

```
only: ["challenge.:_id"]
```

Problem solved!

Comment: in my 20 years of software development i have never had to fish around more online to figure out how to do seemingly simple things than within the meteor stack. thanks for this !

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful to account for when a user is logged in, not logged in, and when they are **logging in**.

The following is code for a `requireLogin` function that I place in a `onBeforeAction` hook.

If there's no Meteor user, check to see if they're logging in, and if so, render a loading template.

```
var requireLogin = function() {
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
    if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
    } else {
      this.render('AdminLogin');
    }
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: ['AdminMain', 'postSubmit', 'appointmentsList', 'AppointmentShow']});
```

**EDIT**

Ok, this is what's happening:

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#applying-hooks-to-specific-routes

What's not perfectly clear from the documentation is what kind of arguments the array takes in the `onBeforeAction`

```
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: ['routeName', 'anotherRouteName']});
```

Here's a set of routes that work with the hook:

```
  this.route('/order', {
    template: 'order',
    name: 'order',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
  });

  this.route('/order/:_id', {
    template: 'order',
    name: 'orderEdit',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    data: function(){
      var id = this.params._id;
      alert(id);
    }
  });

  var beforeHook = function(){
    console.log("beforeHook run!");
    alert("safsf");
  };

  Router.onBeforeAction(beforeHook, {only: ['orderEdit']});
```

Comment: Yep, that works well for all routes.  My code above to run onBefore Hooks for certain routes.  The issue seems to be that the function isn't running on my /challenge routes at all.

Comment: I see. So even if you put like a `console.log` in your hook function it doesn't get fired? I'm also not the best at reading coffeescript.

Comment: Yep!  Tested and saw that it wasn't running.

Comment: answer update - you also need to show us how you defined your routes

Comment: I think it's due to the route having a data param.  I use OnBefore hooks in other places where it's a static url like 'admin' and it's fine.  In this case,  only: ['challenge/:_id'], the function won't run.